# ¿Qué significa "Vaya pepino de base"?

Tags: significado, coloquialismos, españa, música

El rapero valenciano Nega ha dicho *Vaya pepino de base* en las canciones "Retales en mi cuaderno" y "Disparen sobre Leyre Patín" [[sic]](https://images.genius.com/81109bab35271358f4dfadff4ff8fd13.1000x1000x1.jpg). Hay poco contexto, parecen interjecciones, pero así son las letras:

> Ajá, ajá, vaya tela primo, **vaya pepino de base**, 2009, Jean Luc Godard, Yoew en los aparatos,
>
> Nega, creando escuela, 2011, sois unos ingratos, lo hacemos así, Yoew produciendo en los aparatos, en el ático en Angel Guimerá, **vaya pepino de base**, escucha atentamente:

[Una receta de cocina con "pepino de base"](https://www.debate.com.mx/sociales/Totalmente-gourmet-20140130-0267.html) no será. El dicionario de jerga de Carbonell Basset ofrece para *pepino* las opciones de cabeza alargada, billete de mil pesetas, moto, y pene, pero la gramática no me cuadra todavía. ¿Lo pueden explicar Uds.? ¿Qué significa *Vaya pepino de base*?

Comment: Seguramente esté usando "pepino" como sinónimo de "misil" o "bomba", se usa para expresar que algo tiene mucha potencia: "Me he comprado una tarjeta gráfica nueva que es un pepino". Sin más contexto no podemos estar seguros, ni tampoco a qué se refiere con "base", aunque si es un rapero se referirá a una base musical, un ritmo de bajo, batería o lo que sea, que tiene mucha fuerza.

Comment: @Charlie Gracias por eso, bien puede ser. Añadí el contexto que hay. Ni DRAE ni Carbonell Basset notan aquel significado, interesantemente, DRAE tiene uno que sería el opuesto: "Cosa insignificante, de poco o ningún valor"

Comment: La política se llama Leire Pajín, pero veo que hicieron una adaptación

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming': de acuerdo. Quizás fue para no amenazarla tan directamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una base en el hip-hop es una construcción sobre la que rapean. Cuando dicen *vaya pepino de base* están vanagloriándose de la base, la están calificando de muy buena.

En contextos coloquiales es común usar *pepino* para denotar una cualidad superlativa. Así, puede decirse *mi nuevo ordenador es un pepino: se enciende en un plis plas*.

Ese es el significado que yo le veo en el contexto que citas de una canción de hip-hop.

Su uso no es demasiado antiguo, pero parece venir de Madrid:

De [17 palabras madrileñas para que te entiendas fetén con los chulapos de la capital](https://blogs.publico.es/strambotic/2018/01/palabras-madrilenas-feten/):

> Pepino: no, no es un sinónimo de pene, que siempre están ustedes pensando en lo mismo. Se trata de un calificativo para exaltar las cualidades positivas de algo: "Ese coche es un pepino". También se puede usar "pepinaco" para exagerar aún más: "Esa canción es un pepinaco".

Yo lo he oído y usado en otras partes de España (por ejemplo Valencia, de donde es este rapero), pero habría que preguntar a nuestros compañeros hispanoamericanos si la palabra ha cruzado el charco.

Comment: Esto me explica también porque él alaba al señor Yoew. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Exacto! Se lo agradece de una forma grandilocuente, muy al estilo de los raperos